# Cross platform programing with html5?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am new in programming and technology. I would like to know if it is possible to build a HTML5 game that runs as an app in mobile device (i.e., iphone, android, windows phone).

I don't have a macbook to program for iphone.

It's possible?

Comment: Possible, ever heard of [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)?

Comment: to publish as an iphone compatible app you'll need a mac though -- I tried phonegap but had issues (mostly my fault) but plan to revisit because I hear GREAT things about it.   Good luck with everything, its a fun journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn c# and then you don't have to buy a Mac. But, yeah, you can make an html5 app. The technology is now advanced that you can do that. Since you are new to programming, I suggest learning html and JavaScript and the jQuery then jQuery mobile, which will allow you to make web application which function like an app.

Simple answer is that yes you can. Just be determined to learn the languages

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, look into these tools.

- http://phonegap.com/
- http://cordova.apache.org/